# How do I compare Dart Records with deep equality?

Tags: dart, dart3

Dart 3 has introduced a new type `Record`. `Record`s are compared with the `==` operator by each field which means if a `Record` has a `List` or a `Map` as its field, the comparison would be `false` even if the `List`s or `Map`s are structurally the same.

```dart
final record1 = ([1, 2],);
final record2 = ([1, 2],);
print(record1 == record2);
// Prints false
```

How do I compare them with deep equality?

Answer (score 2):

By "deep equality" you mean transitively traversing collections, which are not naturally equal in Dart, and use some other "ListEquality" function to do the equality of those.

There is no easy way. The reason for that is that you cannot abstract over record type. If you want to define an equality on records, which use something else than `==` on the fields of records with the same shape, you need to define one *for each record shape*.

I can give you "Pair":

```dart
import "package:collection/equality.dart";
class PairEquality<A, B> implements Equality<(A, B)> {
  final Equality<A> _first;
  final Equality<B> _second;
  const PairEquality({
    Equality<A> first = const DefaultEquality(), 
    Equality<B> second = const DefaultEquality()})
      : _first = first,
        _second = second;
  
  bool equals((A, B) pair1, (A, B) pair2) =>
    _first.equals(pair1.$1, pair2.$1) &&
    _second.equals(pair1.$2, pair2.$2);

  int hash((A, B) pair) => 
     Object.hash(_first.hash(pair.$1), _second.hash(pair.$2));

  bool isValidKey(Object? pair) => pair is (A, B);
}
```

Even that doesn't help your example, where you have a singleton record, you'd need a class for that as well.

I'll assume that your pairs are not only at the top, because then you could just do:

```dart
var eq = const DeepCollectionEquality();
var record1 = ...;
var record2 = ...;
var equals = eq.equals(record1.$1, record2.$1);
```

So you probably need to *rewrite* the [`DeepCollectionEquality`](https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/blob/master/lib/src/equality.dart#L421)  to recognize the record types you know how to compare (it's not written for injecting more recognized types).

```dart
@override
  bool equals(Object? e1, Object? e2) {
    if (e1 is Set) {
      return e2 is Set && SetEquality(this).equals(e1, e2);
    }
    if (e1 is Map) {
      return e2 is Map && MapEquality(keys: this, values: this).equals(e1, e2);
    }
    if (!_unordered) {
      if (e1 is List) {
        return e2 is List && ListEquality(this).equals(e1, e2);
      }
      if (e1 is Iterable) {
        return e2 is Iterable && IterableEquality(this).equals(e1, e2);
      }
    } else if (e1 is Iterable) {
      if (e1 is List != e2 is List) return false;
      return e2 is Iterable && UnorderedIterableEquality(this).equals(e1, e2);
    } else if (e1 is (Object?, Object?)) {        // new
      return e2 is (Object?, Object?) &&          // new
         PairEquality(this, this).equals(e1, e2); // new
    }  
    return _base.equals(e1, e2);
  }

  @override
  int hash(Object? o) {
    if (o is Set) return SetEquality(this).hash(o);
    if (o is Map) return MapEquality(keys: this, values: this).hash(o);
    if (!_unordered) {
      if (o is List) return ListEquality(this).hash(o);
      if (o is Iterable) return IterableEquality(this).hash(o);
    } else if (o is Iterable) {
      return UnorderedIterableEquality(this).hash(o);
    } else if (o is (Object?, Object?) {        // new
      return PairEquality(this, this).hash(o);  // new
    }
    return _base.hash(o);
  }
```

And you'd need to add new cases for every record shape you need to recognize.

(That suggests that maybe `DeepCollectionEquality` should be parameterizable with some "recognize type and provide an equality for it" objects. But for now, it isn't.)

A possible implementation of such a configurable deep equality could be something like:

```dart
import "package:collection/collection.dart";

/// Builds a recursive equality.
///
/// Allows for easily creating equalities for structures, 
/// like collections or similar, that refer back to the deep equality
/// for element equality.
class DeepEquality implements Equality<Object?> {
  List<Equality<Object?>> _equalities = const [];
  /// Creates recursive equality.
  ///
  /// Each function in [factories] is called with this deep equality
  /// as argument, and should return an equality for a specific type.
  ///
  /// When comparing or hashing, each of these equalities are tried,
  /// in original iteration order, until one's [Equality.isValidKey] 
  /// returns true, then that equality is used on the objects.
  ///
  /// For [equals], both arguments must be valid.
  ///
  /// If no factory-created equality matches, the [base] equality
  /// is used instead. It *must* accept all remaining values.
  DeepEquality(Iterable<Equality<Object?> Function(Equality<Object?>)> factories,
      [Equality<Object?> base = const DefaultEquality()]) {
    _equalities = [for (var factory in factories) factory(this), base];
  }

  @override
  bool equals(Object? a, Object? b) {
    if (identical(a, b)) return true;
    for (var equality in _equalities) {
      if (equality.isValidKey(a) && equality.isValidKey(b)) {
        return equality.equals(a, b);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  int hash(Object? a) {
    for (var equality in _equalities) {
      if (equality.isValidKey(a)) {
        return equality.hash(a);
      }
    }
    return a.hashCode;
  }

  @override
  bool isValidKey(Object? o) => true;
}

/// Creates an [Equality] from equals and hash code functions.
class PredicateEquality<A> implements Equality<A> {
  final bool Function(A, A) _equals;
  final int Function(A) _hash;
  final bool Function(Object?)? _isValid;
  PredicateEquality({
    required bool Function(A, A) equals,
    required int Function(A) hash,
    bool Function(Object?)? isValidKey,
  })  : _equals = equals,
        _hash = hash,
        _isValid = isValidKey;

  @override
  bool equals(A a, A b) => _equals(a, b);
  @override
  int hash(A a) => _hash(a);
  @override
  bool isValidKey(Object? o) => _isValid?.call(o) ?? o is A;
}


// Usage:
void main() {
  var deepListEq = DeepEquality([
    ListEquality.new,
  ], const DefaultEquality());
  print(deepListEq.equals([1, [2, 3]], [1, [2, 3]]));

  var deepPairListEq = DeepEquality([
    ListEquality<Object?>.new,
    (eq) => PredicateEquality<(Object?, Object?)>(
          equals: ((Object?, Object?) pair1, (Object?, Object?) pair2) =>
              eq.equals(pair1.$1, pair2.$1) && eq.equals(pair1.$2, pair2.$2),
          hash: ((Object?, Object?) pair) =>
              Object.hash(eq.hash(pair.$1), eq.hash(pair.$2)),
        )
  ]);

  var v1 = ([1, (1, 2)], [(1, [2])]);
  var v2 = ([1, (1, 2)], [(1, [2])]);
  print(deepPairListEq.equals(v1, v2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[The spec](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/future-releases/records/records-feature-specification.md) says:

> Records have value equality, which means two records are equal if they have the same shape and the corresponding fields are equal.

And there's a lot more about whether records have primitive equality, or even identity, but you'll have to read the spec... I'm not going to cut and paste it here.

My interpretation is that simply using == will suffice for nearly all of your cases where you want "deep" equality.

Comment: Except where the record has collections